# Could someone please assist with the limiting functions of a 0.1 step and no characters and also a min and max value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Here is the code I have so far and the limiting functions that I want the input for to reject

- a step value of 0.1 ie no value smaller than 0.1 ie 0.01
- no characters ie w,r,t
- a min value set by the function input ie 1
- a max value set by the function input ie 5
- please note the way I have written the rest of my code the type of the input form can not be ="number" it must be ="text"

any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
function myFunction(e, low, high) {
  console.log("called");
  console.log("low" + low);
  console.log("high" + high);
  console.log(e.target.value + e.key);

  var charValue = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var nextValue = e.target.value + e.key;
  if (((!/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$/.test(e.target.value + e.key)) && (e.which != 8)) && (nextValue < 1 || nextValue > 5)) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form name="addtext">
  SetPoint :<input id="setPoint" type="text" name="setPoint" onkeydown="myFunction(event,3, 5)" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't you post something similar a few days ago?

Comment: What about the rest of the code prevents you from using `type="number"`?

Comment: @Barmar no one gave me the answer i needed

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of simplifying the `if` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're playing Code Golf, there are no prizes for cramming all the logic into a single condition.

Split the condition into multiple `if` statements so you can implement your logic clearly.

You need to replace the hard-coded `1` and `5` with `low` and `high`.

```js
function myFunction(e, low, high) {
  console.log("called");
  console.log("low" + low);
  console.log("high" + high);

  var nextValue = e.target.value + e.key;
  console.log(nextValue);
  if (e.which == 8) { // allow backspace
    return;
  }
  if (!/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$/.test(nextValue)) {
    e.preventDefault(); // non-number, don't allow
  }
  if (nextValue < low || nextValue > high) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form name="addtext">
  SetPoint :<input id="setPoint" type="text" name="setPoint" onkeydown="myFunction(event,3, 5)" /><br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use an input that is made for this. No javascript required.

```html
<input id="range" value="1" type="range" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="5.0">
```